# Making a basic shell in C and have trouble regarding pipes / forks

Tags: c++, c, unix, fork, pipe

First I'd like to ask why are forks needed in pipes? I'm fairly new to this, but to me I don't yet see why I can't just run one process to the left of the | then have the next part go after using the result as an input. I know forks are used, but I'm not getting why or where I would need them.

Thanks so much for answering this question even though it's probably a stupid question.

Comment: The bottom line is that in a shell environment every `pipe` (e.g.: `echo "stuff" | sort` creates a separate process for each side of the pipe `|` that runs under its own `PID`. (it is the equivalent to `fork` in C). Interprocess communication is done by `pipes`. E.g. in C the `fork` and `popen` functions. No deep mystery -- just the way it works.

Comment: You could implement pipes as you said, by saving all the output of the left hand program to a file, then starting the right hand program reading the file as input. It's just less efficient - the two programs are run sequentially rather than in parallel, you need potentially a lot of disk space, etc. Pipes use very little disk space, on the order of kilobytes.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: pipes use no disk space at all. fifos use very little disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html); it -the ALP book- has *several chapters* explaining this. And perhaps *study* the source code of some free software shell. Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

A [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) has a certain (small) capacity `PIPE_BUF` (a few kilobytes). When that pipe is filled, the writing process is blocked. When the reading process has read everything, the pipe becomes empty, and the reading process is blocked. So the writing process gets a chance to run and write inside it.

So you need both processes to run *simultaneously* (and they could exchange a huge amount of data - eg gigabytes in a few seconds). And  `fork` is the *only* way to make new processes.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` or variants is not only necessary to execute programs that connected by pipes, but to execute any program. The reason for that - `exec..()` functions family replace current process with one that loaded by exec. So for your shell program to continue after child program terminates you have to call `fork()`

For pipes, pipe buffer is relatively small, but amount of data that programs communicate through pipe could be large. For that to work efficiently both programs have to run in parallel.